# Can I mention a very recently started project on my resume?

Tags: resume, internship, work-experience, projects

I'm in my penultimate year. I started working on a project from August 1st under my college professor in collaboration with Samsung research institute. Since it's just been a month, there wasn't much progress made. We just researched about previous works made on this topic and did some installations on the system. Summer internships just begun.

1. As a fresher, I don't have any experience so is it fine to mention this project in experiences section on my resume by including "August 2021 - Present"? (felt it's worth mentioning in experiences as it is a project in collaboration with Samsung research institute.)
2. Or should I not mention it? Since there wasn't much progress made yet. I can't discuss anything technical about it other than explaining what project is all about.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it's not about a month having given you that much meaningful experience, so I'd go by some of my other criteria:

- Is it important to you? Does the nature of the project say something about who you are? Then include it.
- Is it something you'd really like to discuss with prospect employers? Then include it.
- Does its inclusion make your resume longer than one page? Then don't include it, or remove something else in favour of it.